# How to shrink the Eclipse PDOM file?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I understand that the PDOM file is a flat text database containing binary data.  But my issue is that I daily archive (via winzip) my workspaces to ensure I can get back to a working configuration in case something goes bad (which unfortunately seems to happen weekly).  The problem is the PDOM file gets HUGE (e.g. 64 MB).  So creating daily archives is expensive.   Is it possible to shrink and/or delete the PDOM file and still have the poject work?

Thanks

Comment: +1. But come back when the file is 1.5GB

Answer (score 8):

The PDOM files contain the data from the Indexer. So it's nothing you really need to restore your workspace.
So you could simply don't archive it.
The Indexer will re-create it as soon as it misses it.
BTW this is an option to shrink it: Close Eclipse, delete it, start Eclipse and let the Indexer re-create it :-)

Comment: +1. Thank you. This saved me ~ 5GB in old (broken?) PDOM files.